# How to get ui-grid cellClass function called for all visible rows after reorder?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I wrote a cellClass function, rowSpanCellClass, to implement something like HTML rowspan. When a value is repeated in a column where rowSpanCellClass is used, the cells with repeating values will appear to merge vertically.

This works fine when the grid is initially rendered. However, if I reverse the sort order of a different column (docNum), rowSpanCellClass is not called for every row. Therefore, the class of one the cells in the rowSpanCellClass  column is not changed when it should.

Here is [simple plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/W1Yr4g9XRXfRrseG3XdH?p=preview)  demonstrating my problem.

If you click on the Doc Num header twice to reverse the initial sort order, the output to the console shows that rowSpanCellClass is called for all rows except the row with rowRenderIndex = 3.

I believe that row is skipped because it doesn't change when the rows are reordered. rowSpanCellClass needs to be called for all rows because the cell class depends not only on current row value, but on adjacent row values.

I tried to force the cellClass function to be called on every row with the following code

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
      gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, function (grid, sortColumns) {
          gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
      });
  };
```

However, the sortChanged event fires before rows are reordered, so this does not work.

What can I do to have rowSpanCellClass be called on all visible rows AFTER they have been reordered?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using a custom cell template and ng-class instead of cellClass.

```
cellTemplate: '<div ng-class="grid.appScope.rowSpanCellClass(grid, row, col)" title="TOOLTIP">{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>'}
```

The change is in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/T0TQoe?p=preview)